# Should Google Play installs minus uninstalls match active installs?

Tags: google-play-console

I'm a bit confused. For an app in my play console it shows:

- 44k installs
- 41k uninstalls
- 11k active installs

For "**lifetime**" timespan.

But should be ***"installs - uninstalls = active installs"***?

So why are there 11k active installs when according to installs minus uninstalls there should be 3k? I heard that there was a change in counting, also google mentions it in the help document, but they don't explain what exactly they changed.

- Do uninstalls include updates? But why is this not marked in the detail statistic? There is just a differentiation between uninstalls and deactivations.

Answer (score 1):

You'd think so, but it doesn't, not on my app or any screenshot of the dev console I ever saw. I believe this is because active installs is only users that opened the app in the last 30 days, so if 9k people uninstalled in the last 30 days (!) you would see this.

Honestly though, I think even Google doesn't understand this, and it's probably a bug.

Comment: But wasn't active installs on devices where the device was active at least one time? I don't think there's any statistic where the app was opened? But then: if I download the app, open it, uninstall it, I would count as active user?

Comment: I think it would be very rare for a user to install and uninstall without opening, so that's probably not the cause